# Elixir Phoenix Web Framework - File upload

Tags: file, upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir & Phoenix, and my question is very easy.
I'm following this tutorial http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads.
In my controller, I have this line:

```
IO.inspect mail_params
```

In the console, during the file upload process, it prints this:

```
%{"file" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "video/mp4", filename: "video-file.mp4",
   path: "/var/folders/3p/3trj48456_q0tm2kh8g70qjm0000gn/T//plug-1468/multipart-580463-521117-1"},
  "message" => nil, "name" => nil, "phone" => "+1 (111) 111-1111"}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the data in `%Plug.Upload` structure such as filename and path.

Elixir guru should know how :)

Comment: `mail_params["file"].filename` and `mail_params["file"].path`?

Answer (score 3):

You have several methods to access that data. You can either pattern match it out:

```
value = %{
  "file" => %Plug.Upload{
    content_type: "video/mp4", 
    filename: "video-file.mp4",
    path: "/var/folders/3p/3trj48456_q0tm2kh8g70qjm0000gn/T//plug-1468/multipart-580463-521117-1"
  },
  "message" => nil, 
  "name" => nil, 
  "phone" => "+1 (111) 111-1111"
}

%{"file" => struct } = value
IO.inspect struct.filename #will result in "video-file.mp4"
IO.inspect struct.path # will result in "/var/folders/3p/3trj48456_q0tm2kh8g70qjm0000gn/T//plug-1468/multipart-580463-521117-1"
```

or you can access them like that

```
IO.inspect value["file"].filename
```

Basically you have there nested struct in a map. You can access map elements by ["name"] and you can access structs elements by .notation

Comment: @DayvanCowboy Np. feel free to accept my answer when you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
IO.inspect upload.filename
```

You can inspect it to understand the structure. To access it with upload["yourvalue"].filename.